# WiFi Mouse or Keyboard?

Tags: wireless-networking, keyboard, mouse

[Old Reference](https://superuser.com/questions/758771/can-i-use-my-wireless-keyboard-receiver-to-connect-to-internet-via-my-wi-fi-rout?noredirect=1&lq=1)

While I was searching for WiFi mouse or keyboard, I found this link. That was 5 year old discussion. Is technology changed over the time ?

Yesterday a friend of mine told me that one of his senior have WiFi connected mouse. I was surprised and got me curious is that even possible ???

Comment: Your real question should be: Is this even desirable? Short answer: NO.

Comment: iKnow answer for this question is NO. In every possible way. But that doesn't mean iKnow everything.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. If you know the answer, why are you asking? What's the actual question?

Comment: Actual question is "is it possible ? and does such thing exists ?" sorry for not putting it in better words.